# Unicode on Twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I have a web application where we're sending some characters to the Twitter API in unicode format (something like &#x2501).  They show up fine on the Twitter website, Tweetdeck and a few other areas but they show up as text instead of the symbol on the iPhone and a few other places.  How do I send the unicode symbols so they show up correctly on all the Twitter clients/platforms?

Thanks

Comment: A link to an example tweet would really be nice if possible.

Comment: What if you send the character as a character, not `&#x2501`?

Comment: Confused what you mean by just sending it as the character?  This is coming all from backend PHP code.

Comment: Actually just figured out what you meant.  Was able to solve it that way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as it helped - I put it here as answer:

You need to post character as a character, not an entity code.